# Flutter_Beacon Library sample app doesn't detect iBeacons

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I've been trying to use the sample app in the flutter_beacon library to detect beacons nearby and have bought an "*Avvel*" iBeacon that I have set up and can detect using the "*BLE Scanner*" app from the google play store. I made sure to allow location tracking within the sample app, as well as having a constant wifi connection and having my Bluetooth on. It just doesn't pick it up and by that, I mean that I have a spinning circle in the middle of the screen, and in my console in "Android Studio" I get the message

> I/flutter (15631): {"region":{"identifier":"Cubeacon","proximityUUID":"cb10023f-a318-3394-4199-a8730c7c1aec"},"beacons":[]}

every half second or so.
The repo for the sample app is the master branch here: https://github.com/alann-maulana/flutter_beacon.

The phone is an original Pixel but as I said, I can detect the beacon using another beacon detection app so I doubt its a hardware issue.

Below is the image of the screen. (Taken from the android emulator in android studio for ease of screenshotting rather than the actual phone).
image

[image]

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. If you need anything else from me then I would be more than happy to oblige.

Comment: What are the beacon identifiers the second app successfully detects?

Comment: @davidgyoung It displays a code, C2:F7:54:C1:F5:4F
then
Apx Dist: 0.56m   Adv: 1010ms
Major: 49492        Minor: 20469
UUID: EBEFD083-70A2-47C8-9837-E7B5634DF524

Comment: @davidgyoung the UUID is concurrent with what I see when detecting the Beacon using another app on an iPhone 6 so I'm sure that they are detecting the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the beacon region defined in the sample app has Proximity UUID cb10023f-a318-3394-4199-a8730c7c1aec, and the beacon used for testing has Proximity UUID EBEFD083-70A2-47C8-9837-E7B5634DF524.  These must be the same.  To get the program to work, change the region definition in the Flutter sample to match your beacon's UUID: EBEFD083-70A2-47C8-9837-E7B5634DF524.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. Is there a way to set it to detect any beacon, not just ones that I already know the code for?

Comment: I am not an expert on Flutter -- but I am the lead dev of the underlying Android library that Flutter Beacon uses.  The Android library will accept a null value as the first identifier in a region definition and then match any beacon.  So you can try supplying that in the region definition in the Flutter code.  However, iOS does not support a null for the UUID, so that certainly will not work on iOS and the Flutter Beacon code may block you from supplying it for Android in an effort to be platform-neutral.